# JavaScript: how do I make a tooltip follow the cursor *and* flip on collision?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so I have a feeling this is an easily resolved problem; bear with me please.

For my website, I've incorporated a jQuery-based tooltip that follows the cursor. But since its a tool I found online to begin with, I'm having some troubleshooting issues. What I want is for the tooltip to follow the cursor *until* the tooltip collides with the edges of the page; when it does collide, I'd like for it to do something like **collision: "flip"**. I pretty much understand why my attempts haven't been working. I only know how to make it *only* follow the cursor or *only* use **.position()**. I don't get how to incorporate both into a single script without messing up everything else.

Here's the script as it was given on the developer's site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// Tooltip only Text
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
    // Hover over code
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
    .text(title)
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
    // Hover out code
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
    $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('.tooltip')
    .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});
</script>
```

There was also a CSS component. As far as I can tell, this isn't involved in the problem, but in case that it is, voilà.

```
.tooltip {
display:none;
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #333;
background-color:#161616;
border-radius:5px;
padding:10px;
color: #fff;
font-size:12px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Sorry if this is a very dense question, but I've been trying to figure this out all day and I've all but given up at this point.

Again, what I want is for the tooltip to follow the cursor, as it currently does -- but not indefinitely. When following the cursor would cause the tooltip to collide with the window, creating a scrollbar, I want it instead to either appear on the other side of the cursor, or remain static as the cursor moves closer to an edge of the window. *Anything*, in any case, for the content within the tooltip to remain visible regardless of where the cursor goes.

Thank you!

Comment: I created a JSfiddle with your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/usLxzvdg/

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Sorry I misread your question the first time. Here is the solution...

The "trick" is to set the event object as the `of` property value of the object that is passed to `position()`. If the value of the "of" property is an object containing `pageX/pageY`, those values are used. This allows you to easily have something follow the mouse, a common use case.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Tooltip only Text
    $('.masterTooltip').hover(function() {
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
            .text(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        // Hover out code
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mouseXPadding = 20,
            mouseYPadding = 10;
            $('.tooltip').position({
                my: "left+" + mouseXPadding + " top+" + mouseYPadding,
                of: e,
                // within: $('.masterTooltip') // optional to contain tooltip
            });
    });
});
```

Here is another, better imo, version which takes into account the fact that the user might accidentally move his/her mouse over the tooltip (a case which the above doesn't handle well):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var padding = {
            x = 20,
            y = 10
        },
        $tip = $('<p class="tooltip"></p>');

    // Our helper function that moves tip to the mouse
    function moveTipToMouse(event) {
        $tip.position({
            my: "left+" + padding.x+ " top+" + padding.y,
            of: event,
        });
    }

    // Moves tooltip out of the way if the mouse accidentally goes over it
    $tip.mousemove(moveTipToMouse);

    // Tooltip only Text
    $('.masterTooltip').hover(function() {
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $tip.text(title);
        if (!$.contains(document, $tip[0])) {
            $tip.appendTo('body').fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }, function(event) {
        // Hover out code
        // if the mouse exists to the tooltip, no need to hide it
        if ($tip.is(':hover')) {
            return;
        }
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(moveTipToMouse);
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g6wmkzr2/

Comment: This seems to work on paper (and on the fiddle), but it doesn't work when I actually try to add it to the page. If I use this code, none of the tooltips follow the cursor anymore; instead, they appear at the very bottom of the page, under all of the content. Here, I've uploaded the updated code to the site so you can see for yourself if you'd like (http://replayrecordings.com/eldursson/2015_03%20-%20March/cal.html). I think it has to do with the CSS formatting making everything all wonky. I'll keep looking into this myself, but any further help is much appreciated!

Comment: @BaldrEldursson I thought you had jQuery UI on the page. My mistake. A simple loading of that library will make the code work. I tested this by loading jQuery UI via console -- `$.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js')` -- and it worked. Keep in mind, if the tooltip is too long and the browser window too small, "flipping" won't have any impact and the tooltip will still overflow the window.